# How to compare two columns which class is grater using a list of class hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, list, hierarchy

I have a list of classes from greater to lower:

```
classes = ['A','B','C','D']
```

And a Data frame with two columns:

```
 Segmentation 2019 Segmentation  2020
         B              A
         B              A 
         A              B         
         C              C         
         B              D
```

How to make third column with a class value after comparison which class is greater (if equality - remain it) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from the classes list where key is the class and value is the index (which is used as rank because list is from greater to lower)

Then you can create 2 rank columns which would contain the ranks (0 to N -- 0 being greater). Finally, compare the ranks and take the one that's greater in rank (i.e. smaller in value)

```
classes = ['A','B','C','D']
classes_dict = {val: index for index,val in enumerate(classes)}
df['Seg 2019 Rank'] = df['Seg 2019'].map(classes_dict)
df['Seg 2020 Rank'] = df['Seg 2020'].map(classes_dict)
df['greater'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Seg 2019'] if x['Seg 2019 Rank'] < x['Seg 2020 Rank'] else x['Seg 2020'] if x['Seg 2020 Rank'] < x['Seg 2019 Rank'] else "equal" , axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Seg 2019    Seg 2020    Seg 2019 Rank   Seg 2020 Rank   greater
    B   A   1   0   A
    B   A   1   0   A
    A   B   0   1   A
    C   C   2   2   equal
    B   D   1   3   B
```

And if you add a new class (VIP), you can just add it in the list before A and it'll be treated as a greater class

Comment: How does this uses the classes list?

Comment: A class is better than B, B than C etc.
If I wan to add 'VIP' class for example, how it could work ?

Comment: I mean to ask the answer does not take order of the class into consideration.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the purpose of the classes list. Let me update the answer

Comment: Updated the answer to take the classes list in consideration

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for get `Equal` or minimal between both columns:

```
print (df)

  Segmentation 2019 Segmentation 2020
0                 B               VIP
1                 B                 A
2                 A                 B
3                 C                 C
4                 B                 D

classes = ['VIP','A','B','C','D']

df['Segmentation 2020'] = pd.Categorical(df['Segmentation 2020'], 
                                         ordered=True,
                                         categories=classes)
df['Segmentation 2019'] = pd.Categorical(df['Segmentation 2019'], 
                                         ordered=True, 
                                         categories=classes)

mask = df['Segmentation 2019'].eq(df['Segmentation 2020'])
s = df[['Segmentation 2019','Segmentation 2020']].stack().min(level=0)
df['new'] = np.where(mask, 'Equal', s)
print (df)
  Segmentation 2019 Segmentation 2020    new
0                 B               VIP    VIP
1                 B                 A      A
2                 A                 B      A
3                 C                 C  Equal
4                 B                 D      B
```

Or solution with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
classes = ['VIP','A','B','C','D']

df['Segmentation 2020'] = pd.Categorical(df['Segmentation 2020'], 
                                         ordered=True,
                                         categories=classes)
df['Segmentation 2019'] = pd.Categorical(df['Segmentation 2019'], 
                                         ordered=True, 
                                         categories=classes)

mask1 = df['Segmentation 2019'].lt(df['Segmentation 2020'])
mask2 = df['Segmentation 2019'].gt(df['Segmentation 2020'])

df['classes'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], 
                          [df['Segmentation 2019'], df['Segmentation 2020']], 
                          default='Equal')
print (df)
  Segmentation 2019 Segmentation 2020 classes
0                 B               VIP     VIP
1                 B                 A       A
2                 A                 B       A
3                 C                 C   Equal
4                 B                 D       B
```